# How to fix PHP contact-form errors: HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG, MIME_HTML_ONLY, MISSING_DATE

Tags: php, html, contact-form, spamassassin

I'm not good at PHP so please be patient and understandable. The e-mails from my contact-form always go into the spam folder. I ran a test on [this site](http://www.mail-tester.com) and it tells me that

1. there is no HTML tag in my HTML-only message (HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG)
2. my message only has text/html MIME parts and I should add text/plain (MIME_HTML_ONLY)
3. my message has a missing header: date (MISSING_DATE)
4. they don't have a mail server (MX Record) behind my domain name and I should post a DNS record (MX type) for my domain name

I know that some of these questions have been asked before, but I don't know what to do and I think I need personal help. Thanks!

EDIT: I have two more problems:

5. there is no SPF record and I should add my domain name to my DNS zone file
6. the message is not signed by DKIM

My HTML:

```
<div class="contact-form">

        <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact-form-handler.php">
            <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
            <br>
            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
            <br>

            <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="40" required></textarea><br>

            <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="SEND MESSAGE">

        </form>
    </div>
```

My PHP:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: mywebsite.com'; 
$to = 'someone@something.net'; 
$subject = 'Subject-line';
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '. $email. "\r\n" .
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email. "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

$message = nl2br($message);

$status = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if($status)
    { 
        echo '<p>Your Message has been send!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong. Please try again.</p>'; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hint: phpmailer. Do not construct mail yourself if you do not know how

Comment: I see... thanks for your help